# Center Align Text In Swipeable Tabs

Tags: android

I am implementing Swipeable tabs in android using a Viewpager, how can i center align the text in the tabs. I have tried using layout_gravity="center" but that does not work.I am not using a TextView. In the Java code I use :

```
private String[] tabs = { "Action", " Adventure", "Comedy", "Crime",
            "Fantasy", "Historical", "Horror", "Mystery", "Philosophical",
            "Political", "Romance", "Science Fiction", "Thriller",
            "True Story", "Urban" };

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.movie_main);


        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    //  titleStrip = (PagerTitleStrip)findViewById(R.id.pager_title_strip);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));

        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: did you try android:gravity="center" for TextView ? And please share your codes also

Comment: can you post the xml code ?

Comment: I do not use a TextView i use an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `android:orientation="vertical"` or  `android:orientation="horizontal"` in your parent layout.